# getting current checked values of checkbox

Tags: javascript

in the display i already have a checkbox which is checked.

i want recently checked values but the below code is returning all the checkbox values including the already checked value.

i want to get newly checked values
Thanks in advance

code :

```
function updatePermissions(data){ //function

    var chkdValue = null;

    var permissions = data.split(";");
    var htmlData = document.getElementsByName("permission");//name of checkboxes
    for(var k=0;k<htmlData.length;k++){
        if(htmlData[k].checked==true){
            var chkdids = htmlData[k].value;
            alert(chkdids);
        }

    }
```

Comment: how do you expect Javascript to return only "recently checked" boxes? `checked == true` checks if a box is checked. It's up to you to maintain the state and manipulate it.

Comment: You need to explain a bit more what do you wanna say with "newly". I think some more data is in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code similar to following example. Here I am using a hash table to record the changes to the check box. Only when the check box set the hash table gets set. when you click submit I am fetches all the values from hash table and displaying them in a alert. You can directly copy paste this code to your IDE and test. You will understand better

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
        var flag={};
        function set(obj)
        {
            if(document.getElementById(obj.id).checked)
            flag[obj.id]=obj.id;
        }

        function checknew()
        {

            for (key in flag) {
                alert(flag[key]);
            }
            for (key in flag) {
                delete flag[key];
            }

        }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="first" onclick="set(this)"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="second" checked="checked" onclick="set(this)"/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="checknew()"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to set the checked into the array at load time too

Comment: no need this code only checks for changes and hence does not need the set the checked array during load time. Please copy the code and test once. You will understand better

Comment: See my answer for a simpler solution

Comment: your code works when it is checked by default on page load. But suppose if the user wants to check multiple times without refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

Gonna need a better idea of your code but what you could do is you could add an `eventListener` to every checkbox so when it changes, it will push the value of that checkbox into an array. It really depends on how you define "recently"... does that mean during the same session? Or maybe after x amount of time? Maybe you can do a `setTimeout` and after a certain time just clear the array?

```
var checkedArray = [];
var permissions = data.split(";");
$('input[name=permission]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    checkedArray.push(this.value);
  } 
}
//checkedArray should populate with values of checkbox

setTimeout(function() { checkedArray = []; }, 10000); 
//after 10 seconds it will clear checkedArray
```

FYI not sure if this code will actually work. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

something like this... I think. I get the impression you want the value as they happen. So, I put eventListerns on the checkboxes. When they are clicked... alert the value. Of course, you can set a global obj for array, and push them in there for later processing.. etc.. but the idea is to capture the values on the fly. In the callback you can put a "checked" test.

```
var checkBxs = document.getElementsByName("permission");
  for(var i = 0; i < checkBxs.length; i++){
    checkBxs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){console.log(this.value)}, false);
  }
```

using native javascript. You didn't stipulate jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test the [defaultChecked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) property of the box

```
if(htmlData[k].checked && !htmlData[k].defaultChecked){
  var chkdids = htmlData[k].value;
  alert(chkdids);
}
```